# Angular и минификация через gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify

Не могу минифицировать файлы Angular с помощью gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate')

gulp.task('js', function() {
    var source = ['components/itunseApp.js', 'components/factory.js', 'components/config.js', 'components/directive.js', 'components/viewCtrl.js'];
    return gulp.src(source)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js', { newLine: ';' }))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate({

            add: true
        }))
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('components'));
});
gulp.task('watch', ['js'], function() {
    gulp.watch('components/*.js', ['js'])
})
```

Контроллер на котором выдает ошибку

```
itunseApp.controller('viewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'itunesSearch', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, itunesSearch) {
console.log('viewCtrl');
$scope.categoryParam = window.localStorage.getItem('categoryParam') || '';
$scope.searchParam = window.localStorage.getItem("searchParam") || '';
switch ($scope.categoryParam) {
    case "song":
        $scope.entity = 'song';
        $scope.idParam = $routeParams.collectionId || window.localStorage.getItem('idParam');
        break;
    case "music-video":
        $scope.entity = 'musicVideo';
        $scope.idParam = $routeParams.trackId || window.localStorage.getItem('idParam');
        break;
    case "software":
        $scope.entity = 'software';
        $scope.idParam = $routeParams.trackId || window.localStorage.getItem('idParam');
        break;
    case "feature-movie":
        $scope.entity = 'movie';
        $scope.idParam = $routeParams.trackId || window.localStorage.getItem('idParam');
        break;
}
itunesSearch.getInfo("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup", $scope.searchParam, $scope.entity, $scope.arrayParams, $scope.idParam).then(data => {
    $scope.arrayParams = data.array;
});
window.localStorage['idParam'] = $scope.idParam;
```

}]);

Конкретно эти две строчки ему не нравятся

```
itunesSearch.getInfo("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup", $scope.searchParam, $scope.entity, $scope.arrayParams, $scope.idParam).then(data => {
    $scope.arrayParams = data.array;
});
```

Это отдельно написаная фабрика

скрин с ошибкой

http://joxi.ru/n2YeQPRsooQp92

Answer (score 0):

не уверен, но может быть ругается из за того что не обрабатывается исключение при http запросе? попробуйте

```
itunesSearch.getInfo("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup", $scope.searchParam, $scope.entity, $scope.arrayParams, $scope.idParam).then(data => {
    $scope.arrayParams = data.array;
}, error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку 
правильно нужно было вот так написать

```
 itunesSearch.getInfo("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup", $scope.searchParam, $scope.entity, $scope.arrayParams, $scope.idParam).then(function(data) {
    $scope.arrayParams = data.array;
});
```

тоесть gulp не захотел скушать "=>"

Comment: так может заставить его кушать транспилированные файлы? [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) должен помочь с этим.